# As of Winter ’24, Chatter emails are no longer sent from orgs

Tags: chatter, winter24

There are a increasing number of cases where administrators are complaining that the chatter email notifications are not going out after the Winter '24 Salesforce release. What is causing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because Winter '24 requires all Salesforce administrator's to update Sender Name and Email Address to Send Chatter Email Notifications.

This is officially documented [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_experiences_require_sender_email_release_update.htm&release=246&type=5).

From the docs

To increase data security, administrators must provide a From Name and Email Address for Chatter email notifications to continue being sent.

**Where**: This change applies to Lightning Experience and Salesforce Classic in all editions.

**How**: As of Winter ’24, Chatter emails are no longer sent from orgs where the From Name and Email Address fields in Chatter Email Settings are blank.

Go to **Setup | Chatter | Email Settings**, then enter valid values in the From Name and Email Address fields.

Comment: We personally found this out today as well.