# Chatter sender issue after Winter ’24

Tags: chatter, winter24

> As of Winter ’24, Chatter emails are no longer sent from orgs where
> the From Name and Email Address fields in Chatter Email Settings are
> blank.

According to the aforementioned quote, the "From Name" is required.
This means the sender's name will always be the same.
Sender' Name used to be

```
Foo Bar in Chatter  // <= "Foo Bar" is the person who post in chatter
```

My client typically classifies emails by the sender and then distributes them to different individuals.
Is there a solution to address my client's issue?
For instance, can we change the sender in Chatter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [As of Winter ’24, Chatter emails are no longer sent from orgs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/411905/as-of-winter-24-chatter-emails-are-no-longer-sent-from-orgs)

Comment: @DerekF No, That's to resolve the issue of chatter notification emails not being sent
My question is more related to sender.

Comment: I have heard this issue from someone else - it broke all their outlook rules because they relied on the sender being the person who posted...let me ask around.

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC Thank you :( I really need to slove this problem

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you want to change the sender name but Unfortunately,
there is no way to change the sender in Chatter. The sender's name will always be
the same as the person who posted in Chatter.

I hope you gone through the help article.

[Require Sender Name and Email Address to Send Chatter Email Notifications (Release Update)](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_experiences_require_sender_email_release_update.htm&release=246&type=5)